# Loading PyTorch model and receiving error "AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Model' on <module '__main__'>"

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I'm using torch.load() to load a Pytorch model and am receiving the error "AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Model' on <module '**main**'>". Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: I have a .pt file that was sent to me and I am using torch.load(PATH), so is this an issue with the model?

Comment: do you have also a python file with the right model architecture class?

Answer (score 0):

The weights that have been saved must have a class. You should keep the same class and file architecture with the weights you load.

Because `torch.load()` uses `pickle` module implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Even I was facing the same error. What this trying to say is create an instance of your model by calling the class and then do `torch.load()`.
2. If go to one of blogs on [Saving and Loading Models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) by PyTorch and there in **load** section, you can clearly see this line `# Model class must be defined somewhere`.
3. So do the following:

```py
model = ModelClass()
model = torch.load(PATH, , map_location=torch.device('cpu')) #<--- if current device is 'CPU'
model.eval() #<---- To prevent it from going to retraining mode.
```